# Can the semicolon be used in this sentence? Or a comma?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, semicolons

> .....And the answer came just shortly after its silence; she said "you can take the baby...

I read that semicolon can be used in a sentence where there are 2 or more different phrases but with the same subject. But the implementation confuses me and need help understanding it.

You can find the full para in the image (it's only a few lines)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9af6i.jpg

Comment: The whole passage sounds unnatural. Not everything one finds on the internet exemplifies good practice. // That said, semicolons are usually used where the two independent clauses are quite closely related semantically (ie are referring to the same thing; 'with the same subject' is not the way to phrase this). But as Yosef implies, the colon is better here to show an expansion of the first independent clause ('the answer came: [what it was]').

Comment: A colon would be fine, and so would a semicolon. Or a period. It needs a full stop of some kind, not a comma; it's a complete sentence.